# From LA done right:How to show this inequality holds?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, inner-products, proof-explanation

Assume that u,v,w are vectors in a inner product space $V$, then

$||w-1/2(u+v)^{2}||=1/2(||w-v||^{2}+||w+v||^{2})-1/4||u-v||^{2}$

Here is a solution, 
http://linearalgebras.com/6A.html Question 27.
But I cannot find how the author manipulating the equation obtained by plugging in to find the answer. Could someone show the steps explicitly? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hint #1: you mistranscribed the identity. Hint #2: think at how you prove the [length of median](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/triangle/LengthOfMedian.shtml) in a triangle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution you linked is incorrect. You should substitute
$$
a = w-\frac12(u+v)
$$
and
$$
b = \frac12(u-v)
$$
into the identity. Then simplify and rearrange.